# If statement in PHP For loop not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to add the CSS class "selected" to the first accordionButton div created. Why doesn't this work?

```
// Create nav from database
                $chapter_array = get_chapter_names();

                for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($chapter_array); $i++) { 
                    if($i == 0) {
                        $selected = 'selected';
                    }
                    echo '<div class="accordionButton '.$selected.'">'.$chapter_array[$i].'</div>';

                    $page_id_array = get_page_ids($i);

                    echo '<div class="accordionContent">';
                    for ($j=0; $j < sizeof($page_id_array); $j++) { 
                        $page_name = get_page_name($page_id_array[$j]);
                        echo '<a href="?page_id='.$page_id_array[$j].'">'.$page_name.'</a><br />';
                    }
                    echo '</div>';
                }
```

Comment: 'It doesn't work' is quite vague. Always provide a simple explanation of how it doesn't work. An error message, what happens, etc.

Comment: Good point. It doesn't work because ALL accordionButton divs get class 'selected'. Correct answer from @PaulP.R.O below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never set `$selected` back after the first div so this adds that class to every div, because `$selected` always contains the string `'selected'`.

You can set it to the empty string before your if statement:

```
$selected = '';
if($i == 0) {
    $selected = 'selected';
}
```

If you like this better you can also write that as a nice ternary expression:

```
$selected = $i == 0 ? 'selected' : '';
```

Comment: Of course, thank you. Will give you correct answer as soon as I am able (10 min limit).

Comment: @chris_mac Thanks :) I'm glad I could help. Also Kendall is correct. This would've been easier to spot if you said what the problem is rather than just saying that it doesn't work. Remember that for next time :)